# Is it possible to have discord.py send a message in a specified channel if a certain website goes down (and then another when it's back up)?

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to stack overflow but it seems like a good place to ask.

I want my discord bot to send a message in a channel if a website goes down and then another when it comes back up. I don't want it constantly sending messages, only if it receives an error (like a 404, gateway error or if the connection times out) 3 times in a row (to avoid false messages) then another one when it goes back up. I've tried google but had no luck finding anything

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, I tried googling but aside from that no. I don't usually work with python so I'm essentially doing this from super basic knowledge.

Comment: You can use the website [isitdownrightnow](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/google.com.html) for this. You can get the html code with `BeautifulSoup` and check if the site is down. Then you can use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/) for checking the website periodically.

Comment: Thanks mate, as I'm new to stack overflow is there something I need to say or do to mark this solved?

Comment: If I type this as an answer, yes you can mark the answer as an **answer** from the button that's bottom of the downvote button. Was this comment helpful for solving your problem?

Comment: Thanks and yes it was, I would've liked it a bit more if you did it for me (joking of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the website [isitdownrightnow](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/) for this. You can get the html code with BeautifulSoup and check if the site is down. Then you can use [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/) for checking the website periodically.